# Receive response from AJAX POST request

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, request, response

How can I receive the response from my AJAX POST request to a URL?

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    var form = document.getElementById('login-form');
    form.onsubmit = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var user = form.email.value;
        var pass = form.pass.value;
        console.log(user);
        console.log(pass);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:5000/auth/login",
            data: {
                username: user,
                password: pass
            },
            success: function(result) {
                alert('msg');
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert('msg');
            }
        });
        form.reset();
    };
</script>
```

I get the username and password when the user submits a form, which sends a POST request to the URL.

If the POST request is successful (i.e., if the server received a request) it will send a JSON with "login success" message.

I'm having trouble even displaying this response message, as nothing is being displayed after I submit the form.

Comment: How do you know `done`, `fail` and `always` are valid properties on that AJAX object you pass in? https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You're right, I've changed it to success now. It is working.

Comment: yeah `.done()` is used to chain at the end of the call - `$.ajax({ ... }).done(function (...) { ... });` (there's no permalink but use Charlie's link above and scroll like 5/8 down the page)

Comment: I see it now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding success to your ajax request.

```
success: function (msg) {
  console.log(msg)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use JSON.parse(msg) before alert the response because Ajax response is a a json

```
done: function (msg) {
           alert(JSON.parse(msg))
        },
        fail: function (msg) {
              alert(JSON.parse(msg))
        },
        always: function(msg) {
              alert(JSON.parse(msg))
        }
```